# How to configure WebStorm to import individual components?

Tags: webstorm

I am trying to configure WebStorm to auto-import individual components from libraries instead of destructuring them from the overall package.

For example, WebStorm currently auto-imports like this:

```js
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Instead, I would like this:

```js
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
```

I do not see any options to change this in the Settings, but perhaps I'm just missing it?

Comment: the way the IDE auto-imports modules depends on the way they are exported; if the module is exported with the [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export), the 'destructuring' (actually [named](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#syntax)) import is used. For modules exported with the default export, default import is suggested

Comment: There is no way to change that? React-Bootstrap, for example, recommends the second method of importing (I am new to web development).

Comment: no way - importing named export with default import and vice versa will cause errors.

Comment: It doesn't, though. I have no problem with `import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container`, which is a valid import.